# How do I get this PHP script to sort Descending?

Tags: mysql, sorting

```
 <?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Experience</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "xxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name, sum(Experience) FROM Hunters GROUP BY Name         ORDER BY Experience DESC"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I've tried to get this to sort by Experience Descending, but it just won't do it. I'm not sure how to make it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is for displaying experience points.

Comment: I think this should be tagged as mysql and not sorting.

Comment: What result do you get, and what would you want instead?

Comment: It does group by name, but instead of sorting the table from Most Experience down to least, it just posts the totals.

Comment: Is your SQL query showing anything? Before you even play with the PHP, you should execute your Query within your Database (possibly phpmyadmin) and see if it is returning the results you want. The query `SELECT Name, sum(Experience) FROM Hunters GROUP BY Name         ORDER BY Experience DESC`

Comment: Can you show an example of the table, what it shows and what do you want to show?

Comment: It does group by name, but instead of sorting the table from Most Experience down to least, it just posts the totals like this: .                                             Name Experience
Name 1 21
Name 2 8
Name 3 11
Name 4 4
Name 5 16
Name 6    4
Name 7 16
Name 8 1
Name 9 9
Name 10 7

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show the formatted table? Just easier to read that way. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce the table here.  It is live at http://jacreationsbreedables.com/JAJewels/Hunters.php

Comment: I'm still very new and trying to learn. I do appreciate everyone's help! :- )

Answer (score 1):

If you use an aggregated function sort by this  function

```
SELECT Name, sum(Experience) 
FROM Hunters 
GROUP BY Name  
order by sum(Experience) DESC
```

or if the db version support you can use an alias

```
SELECT Name, sum(Experience) tot_experience 
FROM Hunters 
GROUP BY Name  
order by tot_experience  DESC
```